# Javascript/jQuery Capitalize each word with array of exceptions and words with 3 or less characters

Tags: jquery, capitalize

I have this code working: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tFx/

```
$.fn.capitalize = function () {
$.each(this, function () {
    var split = this.value.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
        split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1);
    }
    this.value = split.join(' ');
});
return this;
};

$('.title').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).capitalize();
}).capitalize();
```

I would like to have a **list of words of exceptions**.

Also, I don't want to capitalize words with **3 or less characters**.

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This produces a terrible user experience if the user needs to edit in the middle of the input. I suggest doing it on blur, on form submit, or even on the server.

Comment: @KevinB Mmmm that's right. I didn't test that. Would I need to rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: you would just need to change the event from keyup to blur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tFx/10/

```
$.fn.capitalize = function () {
  var wordsToIgnore = ["to","and","the","it", "or", "that", "this"],
      minLength = 3;
  function getWords(str) {
    return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  }
  this.each(function () {
    var words = getWords(this.value);
    $.each(words,function(i,word) {
      // only continue if word is not in ignore list
      if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
        words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
      }
    });
    this.value = words.join("");
  });
};

$('.title').on('blur', function () {
  $(this).capitalize();
}).capitalize();
```

currently set to ignore words shorter than 3 characters and the ones in the list

Comment: This is working perfect! It's just what I was loooking for! Do you know how could I use 'keyup' to affect the input live while typing but allowing editing something in the middle of the input?

Comment: No because when you do `this.value = "str"`, you lose the insertion point. Unless you know of a way to get and then set the insertion point where it should be after changing the value.

Comment: using some plugin like this http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php to detect the caret position?

Comment: Thanks again. I have just one more problem, if I enter "thAt" it changes it to "ThAt", do you know how to ignore words even if they have capital letters in it?

Comment: Yes, just add `.toLowerCase()` inside of the `indexOf()` after trimming. `...wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word).toLowerCase())...`

Comment: sorry to bother you, I have the caret corrected now and it's working with "keyup", but the problem now with the "keyup" is that apparently it can't check the "wordsToIgnore" so after 3 characters typed, it capitalizes all words. Do you know how could I avoid this? Maybe waiting for a "space" before checking the words? i really don't know how coud I do that. This is my latest code working: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tFx/15/

Comment: The problem is even an incomplete word is still a word. I can't think of an elegant way to solve that other than not using keyup, or not modifying the input at all but instead having a "preview" area where you output the modified text.